# How to query for results in one table and then go on and find other related information with those results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my `user_type_of_therapy` table that has 2 columns `member_num` and `type_of_therapy`. each member be repeated as they can have multiple `type_of_therapy`.

I need to fetch X member information. If there is something then use the `type_of_therapy` (is an ID) and search on `type_of_therapy` table. to get the name of that therapy type.

I know how to do independent queries to fetch that information. but I am very unsure if I can do all that in 1 single query? I found a few examples but nothing that I try seems to work.

This is not an inner join.... I need results from the 2nd table that are a direct link from the first table fetch result.

Comment: This is what an inner join is. All the results from the joined table are directly linked to the main table. And you can filter the main (or the joined table using where).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried JOIN?

```
SELECT user_type_of_therapy.member_num, type_of_therapy.type_of_therapy FROM user_type_of_therapy JOIN type_of_therapy ON type_of_therapy.type_of_therapy = user_type_of_therapy.type_of_therapy
```

Comment: No. Its more complicateed than that. I want results from one query that are dependant on another query

Comment: You said that you know how to do with independent queries.. Post them here to analyse them...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use joins (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).
To get user data and therapy name you can do (I'm using arbitrary table names, since I don't know your exact table structure):

```
SELECT
    user.*, type_of_therapy.name
FROM users
    INNER JOIN user_type_of_therapy ON
        users.member_num = user_type_of_therapy.member_num
    INNER JOIN type_of_therapy ON
        user_type_of_therapy.type_of_therapy = type_of_therapy.type_of_therapy
WHERE
    users.[whatever filter you want to use for the users]
```

or if you don't want to get all the types as separate rows, add GROUP BY users.member_num at the end of the query and do

```
SELECT user.*, GROUP_CONCAT(type_of_therapy.name SEPARATOR ',') as types_of_therapy
```

This way you can get all the types of therapy in one column.